# With rlang, convert contents of `...` to a character vector

Tags: r, rlang

I'd like to be able to create a character vector based on the names supplied to the `...` part of a function.

For instance, if I have the function `foo(...)` and I type `foo(x, y)`, how do I create a character vector that looks like `c("x", "y")`?

I'm most interested in figuring out how to use `rlang` for this, but `base` solutions would be great as well.

Comment: Not a dupe, but I asked a similar question a couple months ago and got answers that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50555526/5325862

Comment: Thanks, @camille! You're right, this is very closely related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
foo <- function(...) unname(purrr::map_chr(rlang::exprs(...), as.character))
foo(x, y)
#[1] "x" "y"

identical(foo(x, y), c("x", "y"))
#[1] TRUE
```

Alternatively we can use `as.character` directly on the `list` returned from `rlang::exprs`

```
foo <- function(...) as.character(rlang::exprs(...))
```

---

In response to @joran's question, I'm not sure to be honest; consider the following case

```
as.character(rlang::exprs(NULL, a, b))
#[1] "NULL" "a" "b"

map_chr(rlang::exprs(NULL, a, b), as.character)
#Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

So `as.character` converts `NULL` to `"NULL"` whereas `map_chr(..., as.character)` throws an error on account of the `NULL` `list` entry.

Comment: Is there a situation where just `as.character(exprs(...))` would fail?

Comment: @joran Hmm, good question. I'm not sure TBH; from what I can tell, there seems to be a difference in the way `NULL` entries are treated.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for! Thanks to @joran and your answer, I know to be careful about NULL values.

Comment: Great and glad it helped @bschneidr

Comment: You can also consider: `foo <- function(...) purrr:::map_chr(rlang::quos(...), rlang::quo_text)`