# How to get tidy dots to accept a variable range

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I found this [very helpful article](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) on how to write a function accepting variable arguments using quosure and tidy dots. Here's some of the code:

```r
my.summary <- function(df.name=df_tp1, group_var, ...) {
    group_var <- enquo(group_var)
    smry_vars <- enquos(..., .named = TRUE)

    the.mean <- purrr::map(smry_vars, function(var) {
        expr(mean(!!var, na.rm = TRUE))
    })
    names(the.mean) <- paste0("mean-", names(the.mean))

   df.name %>%
        group_by(!!group_var) %>%
        summarise(!!!the.mean)
}
```

The problem is I have to call the function with a long string of variables, like this:

```r
cm_all1 <- my.summary(df_tp1_cm, group_var=net_role, so_part_value, cult_ci, cult_sn, cult_ebc, sl_t_lrn, sl_xt_lrn, nl_netops_km, so_rt, nl_netops_trust)
```

I would be very happy to be able to just call it with something like

```
so_part_value:nl_netops_trust
```

instead, but this gives errors like this:

```
Error in so_part_value:nl_netops_trust : NA/NaN argument
```

I also tried putting the variable names in a character vector and then using enquo() and !! but that didn't work.

### I'd appreciate any ideas.

Here is my rewrite of the function using Yifu's ideas. This works for my fake data set but not the real data.

```r
my.summary <- function(df.name=df_tp1, group_var, ...) {
##    group_var <- enquo(group_var)
    smry_vars <- df.name %>% select(...) %>% colnames()

    df.name %>%
        ##        group_by(!!group_var) %>%
        group_by({{group_var}}) %>%
        summarise_at(smry_vars,
                     list(mean=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                          sd=function(x) sd(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                          min=function(x) min(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                          max=function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                          q1=function(x) quantile(x, .25, na.rm=TRUE),
                          q2=function(x) quantile(x, .50, na.rm=TRUE),
                          q3=function(x) quantile(x, .75, na.rm=TRUE),
                          n=function(x) n()
                          ))
}
```

Comment: Yes, right. tidy dots==dot dot dot

Comment: I know you didn't write the linked page, but that's a pretty interesting renaming. I'm pretty sure the `...` (ellipsis) has been around since the days of S in the 1980s, as a precursor to R even existing.

Comment: Here's a similar question I posted a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555526/rlang-get-names-from-with-colon-shortcut-in-nse-function

Comment: In this case using `summarise_at` would be quite a lot easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make sure `...` is in the correct environment(the `df` you provided in this example). And then you can use `colnames()` to extract the column name.

```r
library(rlang)
get_column_range <- function(df,...){

    writeLines("Column names as string:")
    print(df %>% select(...) %>% colnames())
    writeLines("Convert back to symbols")
    print(syms(df %>% select(...) %>% colnames()))
}

get_column_range(df = iris,Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

```
Column names as string:
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
Convert to symbol
[[1]]
Sepal.Length

[[2]]
Sepal.Width

[[3]]
Petal.Length

[[4]]
Petal.Width
```

And `dplyr` functions with `_at` suffix also accept string as variable, you don't have to convert them to quosure and then unquote them.

Note that `{{}}` is a easier syntax to learn, it quotes and unquotes at the same time:

```r
my.summary <- function(df,group_var,...){
    column_names <- df %>% select(...) %>% colnames()

    df %>%
        group_by({{group_var}}) %>%
        summarise_at(column_names,list(mean = mean))
}

my.summary(df = iris,group_var = Species,Sepal.Length:Petal.Width)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Species    Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean Petal.Length_mean Petal.Width_mean
  <fct>                  <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1 setosa                  5.01             3.43              1.46            0.246
2 versicolor              5.94             2.77              4.26            1.33 
3 virginica               6.59             2.97              5.55            2.03
```

For more, you can read at: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html

Comment: This is great. It works fine for my fake data frame:
my.summary(df, grp, x:z)
but when I run it with my real data frame:
cm_all1 <- my.summary(df_tp1_cm, group_var=net_role, so_part_value:nl_netops_trust)
I get this message: Error in is_string(x) : object 'so_part_value' not found
(Of course, that column, so_part_value, is in the data frame. Can't figure it out.

Comment: Using the first example function `get_column_range()`, Are you able to print the column names?

Comment: If that's the case, then the columns should be correctly selected. My solution actually uses a different approach than the post you mentioned. I'm using `summarise_at()` which accepts character vector as input. If you are not using `summarise_at()`, you need to convert the column names to symbol using `syms(column_names)` or  to quosure using `quos(!!!syms(column_names))`.

Comment: I am using summarise_at(), just as you wrote in your explanation. The weird thing is that it works for my fake data frame, but not for the real data.

Comment: Then that's really strange. Do you have any codes in the function that modifies the column names? Because the error message means the column name doesn't exist.

Comment: I found a typo in your function, I changed `df` to `df.name` and the function works in iris and diamonds data set. I'm not able to replicate your error.

Comment: OK, that fixed it. I'm a dummy. Thanks very much, Yifu.